# How to draw irregular shape with x and y axis with Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to create this:

[image: 1]

I have been able to create the irregular shape, even if it is not similar, the problem is how to add the x tick and y tick such as K, d, y, a, x, b ? at certain tick. Not the usual 0,1,2,3..

this is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{axis line style/.style={thin, gray, -stealth}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,>=latex,x=1cm,y=0.8cm]
        \draw plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.7);
        
        % x axis and y axis with ticks
        
        \draw [axis line style] (-4.5,-4) -- (5.5,-4);% x-axis
        \draw [axis line style] (-3,-4.5) -- (-3,5.5);% y-axis
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[12pt, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                backgrounds, 
                decorations.pathreplacing,%
                    calligraphy,% had to be after                 
                intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
scale=2,
>=latex,
arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=2]}, semithick},
BC/.style args = {#1/#2}{
        decorate,
        decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=6pt,
        pre =moveto, pre  length=1pt,
        post=moveto, post length=1pt,
        raise=#1},
        ultra thick,
        pen colour={#2}
        },
lbl/.style = {font=\Large}
                        ]
% axis
\draw [arr] (-3,-3) coordinate (aux) 
                    -- ++ (7,0) node[below left=1mm] {$x$};% x-axis
\draw [arr] (-3,-3) -- ++ (0,7) node[below left=1mm] {$x$};% y-axis
% iregular shape
\pgfmathsetseed{8}
\path[draw=blue!50, ultra thick, fill= blue!50, fill opacity=0.5,
      name path=A]  
      plot[domain=0:350, smooth cycle] (\x:2+rnd*0.8);
% intersections
\path[name path=X]  (-1,-4) -- ++ (0,7);
\path[name path=Y]  (-4,1)  -- ++ (7,0);

\draw [name intersections={of=A and X, by={x1, x2}},
       draw=blue, thick]    (x1) -- (x2);
\draw [name intersections={of=A and Y, by={y1, y2}},
       draw=blue, thick]    (y1) -- (y2);
% braces
\draw[BC=3pt/red]   (x1) -- node[lbl, right=5pt] {$h(x)$} (x2);
\draw[BC=3pt/red]   (y1) -- node[lbl, below=5pt] {$w(y)$} (y2);
% ticks
\draw   (x1 |- aux) ++ (0,0.1)-- ++ (0,-0.2) node[below] {$x$}
        (y1 -| aux) ++ (0.1,0)-- ++ (-0.2,0) node[left]  {$y$}
        (-2.62,-2.9) -- ++ (0,-0.2) node[below] {$a$}
        ( 2.75,-2.9) -- ++ (0,-0.2) node[below]  {$b$}
        (-2.9,-2.62) -- ++ (-0.2,0) node[left] {$c$}
        (-2.9,+2.75) -- ++ (-0.2,0) node[left]  {$d$}
         ;
% grid, for finding min and max shape values   
% after their finding, you can delete  both grids    
\scoped[on background layer]
{    
\draw[gray!30] (-3,-3) grid[step= 2mm] (3,3);
\draw[gray]    (-3,-3) grid[step=10mm] (3,3);
}
\foreach \i in {-2,...,2}
{
    \node[above, fill=white, font=\scriptsize] at (\i,-3) {$\i$};
    \node[right,  fill=white, font=\scriptsize] at (-3,\i) {$\i$};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

*Note*: In real document remove code after comment

```
% grid, for finding min and max shape values,
% after their finding, you can delete  both grids
```